# Selenium ChromeDriver Dies With "The driver server has died."

Tags: php, selenium

I'm trying to run ChromeDriver to interact with a page, but the driver dies for reasons unknown. I'm using the ChromeDriver with `ChromeDriver::start();` and am able to interact with a few pages before it dies. I have attached the stack trace below.

It always happens in the same spot, right after clicking a button that should trigger an AJAX call that updates the page contents. I wait for the async request to finish and then attempt to call `findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('foo'))`. It's then that it dies. I'm sure there's something going wrong and killing the process, but I cannot locate and logs that would tell me anything.

What's causing this and how can I debug it?

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverException: The driver server has died. in /home/foo/projects/bar/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/Service/DriverCommandExecutor.php:63
Stack trace:
#0 /home/foo/projects/bar/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php(535): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\Service\DriverCommandExecutor->execute(Object(Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\WebDriverCommand))
#1 /home/foo/projects/bar/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php(175): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver->execute('findElement', Array)
#2 /home/foo/projects/bar/baz.php(80): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver->findElement(Object(Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy))
#3 {main}
  thrown in /home/foo/projects/bar/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/Service/DriverCommandExecutor.php on line 63
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, it suddenly started working properly when I killed all running processes of the the ChromeDriver executable. Maybe something gave it bad internal state?